# Making a table display records from multiple tables and as well as adding new records at the same time

Tags: database, ms-access, foreign-keys

Basically I have 2 tables with records in them.  What I want to do is have a another table that displays records from those 2 tables. I also want that table to automatically add a new record whenever a new record is added in the original 2 tables.

For example:

```
Table 1: Name, Age, Gender
Joe, 24, Male

Table 2: CarMake, Model, Year
Ford,Focus, 2010
```

The other table would then display:

```
ID: 1, Joe, 24, Male,
ID: 2, Ford, Focus, 2010
ID: 3, (whichever out of the 2 tables adds a records first) and so on
```

Whenever a new record is added from table 1 or table 2, it will be added to the 3rd table.

How do i go about in doing this? Would I need to use a foreign key? Still new to access/databases.

Sorry for my bad englsh.

Comment: Which version of MS Access data macros are comparable to triggers and are available in Access 2010. However, it would be better to eplain the problem you wish to solve with this unorthodox approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing that you can use in access that will provide this functionality. If you were using a full database, such as SQL Server, then you could use a trigger.

However, you should back up and figure out what problem you are trying to solve with this design.

If you just want to display a list of the records in the order that they were created, you wouldn't need another table, you just need to record the date and time that each record is created in each table.

You could then use a [union](http://www.fabalou.com/Access/Queries/unionquery.asp) to get the information from both tables (roughly):

```
  SELECT Name + ', ' + Age + ', ' + Gender As Description ,
         DateCreated
    FROM Table1

  UNION

  SELECT CarMake + ', ' + Model + ', ' + Year As Description ,
         DateCreated
    FROM Table2

ORDER BY DateCreated
```

Alternatively, if you have to have a third table, then you will need to modify your code that writes the records into the database to write the third table.